# First 3 cells are the same but turn correct once I start scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So Whenever I launch my app it looks like this and the first 3 cells are all the same. But once I start scrolling up and down it fixes and cell 2 and 3 show the correct information.

This is currently how my code looks like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyFeedCell";
    SampleTableCell *cell = (SampleTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SampleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (SampleTableCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [_allEntries count];
    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:(count-row-1)];
    NSString *imageString = entry.image;
    imageString = [imageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"128x67" withString:@"768x432"];
    NSLog(@"IMAGE : %@", imageString);

    NSURL *imgURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageString];
    [cell.profilePicture setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil]];
    NSString *date = [entry.articleDate substringToIndex:12];
    cell.datePosted.text = date;
    cell.name.text = entry.articleTitle;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    return cell;
}
```

Here's a gif of how it's currently functioning
http://gyazo.com/2011099496257445c008a717beabd8fd

Comment: Just to be sure, NSLog(@"IMAGE : %@", imageString); is printing out three different imageStrings correct?

Comment: It's printing 30+ strings with the same image.

Comment: why can't you do `RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`? Also if you NSLog `_allEntries` are all the images the same like you stated above?

Comment: Because I'm trying to reverse the tableview cells

Answer (score 0):

The whole topLevelObjects gambit is no longer necessary, replace your code with this and see if your still getting the problem:

```
//this above @interface
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyFeedCell";

//Put this in viewDidLoad
[self.table registerClass:[SampleTableCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[self.table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SampleTableCell *cell = (SampleTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

       // Configure the cell.
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [_allEntries count];
    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:(count-row-1)];

    NSString *imageString = entry.image;
    imageString = [imageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"128x67" withString:@"768x432"];
    NSLog(@"IMAGE : %@", imageString);

    NSURL *imgURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageString];
    [cell.profilePicture setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil]];

    NSString *date = [entry.articleDate substringToIndex:12];
    cell.datePosted.text = date;
    cell.name.text = entry.articleTitle;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Then you have the xib and tableCell subclass setup wrong. There is obviously and issue with how the cells are being reused, check your xib and tableCell setup to make sure files owner and everything is correct. I've had this problem before and turned out that my xib setup was wrong. I would try to fix it to use the code I posted above over the topLevelObjects hack.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, switch the registerClass and registerNib lines around (I updated it in my post). You have to call registerNib after calling registerClass.

Comment: My app runs now, that's a good sign. But it still displays the same 3 cells at the top and the NSlog(@"Image: "); gets called over 30 times for sure.

Comment: It's getting called but are the first three output different? Maybe try calling -reloadData in -viewDidAppear

Comment: I'm taking data via RSS, can you TV ?

Comment: Still no luck at all.

Comment: At least in my experience, you don't need to register the class at all if you make the cell in a xib. I only register the class if I make the cell entirely in code, or I'm using the default table view you get by instantiating a UITableViewController (and then you just register UITableViewCell).